# Is there a better alternative to jQuery toggle() to show/hide a text?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to show / hide a text extention with a certain `.class` inside a form. By selecting the rodio with the correct `.class` the extention should show. When selecting any other option within the form, the extention should hide. I tried it with the jQuery toggle() function but by clicking a second time on any of the radios the extention - regardless if selected or not - shows or hides again.

It should show only if the radio with this `.class`is selected:

> span class="span_home_2"

The toggle() I tried it is this:

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input").click(function(){
        $(".span_home_2").toggle();
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<form class="banner_location_box">
    <label class="label_head">
        <?php echo $lang ['select_page']; ?>
    </label>
    <br/>
    <label class="select_page">
        <input type="radio" class="select_location" name="page_id" value="1" checked="checked"/>
        <span><?php echo $lang ['home']; ?><span class="span_home_2">(<?php echo $lang ['available_only']; ?>)</span></span>
    </label>
    <br/>
    <label class="select_page">
        <input type="radio" class="select_location" name="page_id" value="2"/>
        <span><?php echo $lang ['business']; ?></span>
    </label>
    <br/>
    <label class="select_page">
        <input type="radio" class="select_location" name="page_id" value="3"/>
        <span><?php echo $lang ['jobs']; ?></span>
    </label>
    <br/>
</form>
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: By reading [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com). I'm sorry, but that's really the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input").click(function () {
        $(this).parent().find("span").toggle();
    });
});
```

### Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/9sFmV/2/)

Another option:

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
$("input").click(function(){
    $("span").toggle();
});
```

To this:

```
$("input").click(function(){
    $("span.span_home_2").toggle();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it's the very first time that I'm trying something with jQuery but this workes only with every even option. 2. / 4. etc... Any idear why?

Comment: Your question is unclear and I can't understand what you want to do. If you don't explain, I can't help you.

Comment: The form has in total 11 [label], I changed the [$("span").toggle();] to [$("span.span_home_2").toggle();
]
and it workes with every even label such as the 2nd, 4th, 6th etc. whenever selected the [span] hides but when selecting the 3rd, 5th etc. label it shows again. How to solve that?

Comment: Ok I know that it's not working, but how do you want it to work? Which button do you want to be able to press, and what do you want the button to do when you press it?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("input").click(function(){
          $(".span_home_2").toggle();
     });
});
```

Comment: Same problem as with Jonny Sooter's solution, doesn't work with the odd labels (3rd, 5th, 7th etc...)